# What previous Shimano road shifters are 10sp and exit cables under bar tape?

Tags: shimano, shifter, road

I'm swapping out some parts on an old road bike I have to build it up as a winter/less cared about run around. Looking for what I can on auction sites etc., but the model numbers elude me.

I have a 10sp cassette and a compact double up front.

I need a pair of Shimano STI shifters for 10 x 2, and I'm looking for the models which hide the cables all under the bar tape.

So far I'm looking at 105 ST-5700 pair, and Ultegra ST-6700 pair. Is there a Dura Ace model, which I presume the Ultegra and 105 were originaly designed off, but from the year or so earlier?

ST-7801 appears to have the front inner side exit I don't want, and also the model number doesn't seem right to me but they never all made sense.

I don't know what the term for the cables exiting under the bar tape is to search for that, does Shimano have a particular marketing term for it?

Comment: A winter bike, with Dura Ace or Ultegra?  Could be a bit expensive for a bike that will be "less cared about"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shimano calls this 'hidden brake and shift cables.'

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-r2000/ST-R2000-L.html

First on Dura-Ace 7900

There is a list of 10-speed groupsets here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Road_groupsets

Then:

- Dura-Ace 7900
- Ultegra 6700
- 105 5700
- (Tiagra 4600 does NOT have the hidden cables and is based on an older design.)
- Tiagra 4700
- (Not listed there and irrelevant unless you have hydro disc brakes, but ST-RX400)

7900 and 6700 are almost identical internally (both contain ball bearings). 5700 is a bushing design, as is 4700.

4700 is essentially an R9100/R8000/R7000 design; i.e. the brake cable/lever follows 'SLR EV' design, rather than 'New Super SLR'. It also uses the 11-speed RD pull ratio (along with GRX 10 speed), which pulls more cable and is therefore easier to setup and generally better. So you can use any 11-speed RD with this, or RD-4700/RD-RX400 10-speed RDs. But not the older 10-speed road RDs.

7900 revised the brake pull ratio, so your bike will stop poorly if you mix 7900 with brakes BEFORE 7900/6700/5700/4600/3500/2400, but you can mix it with newer design (symmetrical pivots on the arms, rather than one on the arm and one on the top - symmetrical design is called SLR EV), R9000/R8000/R7100/6800/5800/5810 brakes

I would go for the 4700 brifters rather than any older ones.

In terms of FD, assuming you will use band-on, then 4700 has the long-arm design:

[image]

the increased leverage here means it should shift better than the 7900/6700/5700, design

[image]

(note that 7900/6700/5700 introduced a new pull ratio, which as indicated above did not propagate to 4600, which was older.)

[also note that the long arm created problems with cable routing on certain braze-on frames, so they updated it again for the current R9100/R8000/R7000 series)

Comment: Where does it have those ball bearings vs. bushings.

Comment: I don't think Shimano produces exploded diagrams of the internals of the shifting unit, but it's in there. see here https://youtu.be/wJj6dASBMN0?t=185

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia Shimano page has nice tables of mountain and [road](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Road_groupsets) groupset series. That should clarify how the series numbers work, and you can identify 10 speed groups

The product codes for drop bar shifters are of the form ST-*Series Number* e.g. ‘ST-5600’ for 5600 series 105 circa 2006. Use Google image search on those codes, and you’ll easily determine which models have side or under bar tap routing.

Answer (score 1):

105 -- 5700 /
Ultegra -- 6700 /
Dura Ace -- 7900/

Comment: thanks! wow, those 7900 still command a real premium hey!

Comment: They really do. The 105 shifters are good but the ultegras are a worthwhiie step up.